# Duplicate Text not entering collection

Tags: mesh, 3d-view, text-object, outliner

In the image below, there a text selected in the 3d-window "deudoni". The text is parented to the mesh (box) it's in front of. Each box has its own text on it. Each box is in its own collection.

The selected text `Text.003` is in its own collection too, but if you go to the *Outliner*, there's a duplicate just outside the collection `Text.003`. I don't even know if it's a duplicate.

If I delete the text outside the collection, the text inside the collection also deletes.

If I hide the text outside the collection, the text inside the collection also hides too.

I don't know why that happens.

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/217999/collection-move-vs-link/218004#218004

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put an object in different collections, it will be called a linked object (not the same as imported linked objects), but it will be the same object, not a duplication. To link an object to another collection in the *Outliner* or in the 3D view press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> or in the *Outliner* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> drag and drop the object. To unlink, in the *Outliner*, press <kbd>RMB</kbd> > *Unlink*.

Comment: Thank you. I've fixed it just now.