Node appears twice after assigning parent (Python)
I am creating six cubes and then I set their parent to Box1. Afterwards all cubes exist twice: one time under the Collection and one time greyed out under the Box1 node. When I click one node, the other node with the same name will also be selected. This is annoying and I don't want to have two same nodes. How can I make that they only appear once?
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(
        size=1,
        enter_editmode=False,
        align="WORLD",
        location=location,
        scale=dimensions,
    )

    self.blender_object = bpy.context.object 
    self.blender_object.parent = self.parent.blender_object # self.parent.blender_object is "Box1"



that's normal behavior. The cubes are in the Collection and they are children of Box1 which is in the Scene Collection. Since the cubes cannot be in 2 collections at the same time they are displayed normally in Collection and greyed out in Scene Collection where the parent is. Move Box1 to Collection if you want them to stay together.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/217999/collection-move-vs-link/
